# Rescaling videos with FFMPEG for iDVD

Tags: video, encoding, dvd, idvd

I am preparing a DVD with several 10-minute videos in mp4 (produced from Final Cut Pro or Adobe Premiere), 1920x1080. I am using iDVD version 7.1 (1145) and macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

When I export the project into an .iso image, it spends a few hours encoding the menus, and then a few more encoding the first video, and suggests 30 hours to encode them all. I stopped the process and used FFMPEG to encode the videos to a PAL DVD format, following https://www.kevssite.com/converting-a-video-file-to-dvd-with-ffmpeg/:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -y -target pal-dvd -qscale 0 -aspect 16:9 output.mpg
```

I can add this video to the DVD, but it shows a warning sign and clicking on it shows a broken link:

[image: Video format fails to render in iDVD]

I tried other commands, such as scaling directly to 720p with `-vf scale=720:-1` but it also shows the same broken link. I also tried [this script](https://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?p=1809116#post1809116), which does not produce an output because the setting for the bitrate is too low.

How can I convert MP4 files to 720x576 for a PAL DVD with FFMPEG, so that iDVD encodes faster?